# Convert pdf to text returns weird escape sentences

Tags: pdf, apache-tika, pdfminer, pdftotext, calibre

I am trying to extract text from pdf to text. The pdf contains text in Czech, which includes characters such as ščřžý...
I tried numerous approaches including tika, textract, texttopdf, calibre, PDFMiner and so on.
However, I am getting many undefined characters and some characters are incorrectly decoded. 
I also tried to encode and decode the text with different codecs, but got no luck.
Could you suggest possible solutions to this problem?
So far, OCR worked best, but mistakes o (the letter) for 0 (zero) and some letters are capitalised.

Comment: Is this a PDF of real text? (eg open in Acrobat, highlight, copy and proper text comes out) Or is a PDF of a scan of text (so an image)?

Comment: It is a proper pdf. I am able to copy the text from there. But the copy manual copy has the same flaws.

Comment: Hmm, maybe an image with OCR'd text put behind it? If you ask Tika to extract embedded stuff, do you get images out?

Comment: I havent tried that yet. Do you mean it should extract some of the letters as images?

Comment: *"But the copy manual copy has the same flaws"* - that usually means that the information for text extraction in the pdf are incomplete or even incorrect. Please share the pdf for further analysis.